# Trying to sort letters characters in a specific way but can't quite get it right

Tags: algorithm, sorting, python-3.x

There is a puzzle on https://www.codingame.com/ that I have been trying to figure out for a while. You have sort a specific set of letters in a specific format. say the input is:

> abbcccdddd

then the output would be:

> 1a2b3c4d

Here is my code:

```
s = input()

lstr = list(s)

hold = []
fullstr = ''



for c in lstr:
    if len(hold) == 0:
        hold.append(c)
    elif c == hold[len(hold) - 1] and c != lstr[len(lstr) - 1]:
        hold.append(c)
    elif c != hold[len(hold) - 1]:
        fullstr += str(len(hold))
        fullstr += str(hold[len(hold)-1])
        hold[:] = []
        hold.append(c)
        if c == lstr[len(lstr) - 1]:
            break


print(fullstr)
```

Now this works, until I get to the last set of characters. For example, I'll use the same example from above, if I input:

> abbcccdddd

I will get:

> 1a2b3c

No matter what I try I cannot get the last number and character, any ideas?

Comment: Note that `hold` still contains `'d'` at the end of the loop - you don't actually deal with the last letter. Also you could make this much simpler with a `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Then just use a regular dictionary. Also, note that `[-1]` accesses the last element in a sequence.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks but i cant use modules. How do you think I can fix the for loop?

Comment: This is called [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).  It's different from sorting.

Comment: @JeffIrwin Didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not store n times the same character, just increment an int

```
s = input()
lstr = list(s)

current = ''
nb_current = 0
fullstr = ''

for c in lstr:
    if nb_current ==0: #only for the first character of the list
        current = c
        nb_current = 1
    elif c==current:
        nb_current += 1
    else:
        fullstr += str(nb_current)
        fullstr += current
        current = c
        nb_current = 1

if nb_current>0:
    fullstr += str(nb_current)
    fullstr += current

print(fullstr)
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what I was doing wrong.